# redirect to another page (setTimeout) won't stop loading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, blogger

i use this script

```
setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = '/MyPage';
     }, 5000);
```

it already redirect me ,but never stop loading each 5 second, so how to redirect to (/MyPage) but after reach want to stay without loading

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem. What is the reason you want to reload in the first place? You can set a hash value to test if you already had been reloaded: `if (!location.hash) window.location.href = '/MyPage#reloaded';`

Comment: Does that same script appear on the new page? All scripts _should_ be reset on navigation, so there's something unusual going on!

Comment: Assuming this code is on the `/MyPage` itself then every time the page loads, you're telling it to reload again in 5 seconds. You need to set a flag somewhere which keeps state across page requests, such as localStorage or a cookie, and then only redirect based on that flag.

Comment: @mplungjan 
you misunderstand me, i do won't to reload. i need to stop reload after redirect.

Comment: I did not misunderstand. There is normally a reason to reload. What is the reason for you to think you need to reload at all? Also the code I posted will stop the reload if you add the hash only when you reload

Comment: @mplungjan 
it works right now . thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that this script should redirect to itself. Then you can set an entry in your local storage like:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('foo')) {
    localStorage.setItem('foo', '1');
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = '/MyPage';
    }, 5000);
}
```

If you want to reenable the redirect, you can delete the entry with:

```
localStorage.removeItem('foo');
```

Alternatively you can also set a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).